# Kids climbing fence to pass through yard - homeowner's liablity?

Tags: liability, massachusetts, trespass, hypothetical

Suppose a property owner does not mind if children, say aged 11 to 13, climb over their fence to use their property as a shortcut.

What would their liability be if one of these children hurt themselves while climbing the fence?

Would it make any difference if there was a large bin left next to the fence that made it easier for the children to climb over, as opposed to installing a gate in the fence instead?

Comment: Why haven't you asked this of your lawyer? We cannot provide specific legal advice here, and nothing we say could be as useful as a discussion with someone who has passed the bar necessary. If you think you can't afford a lawyer, you definitely can't afford to not have one.

Comment: At least as edited this is not a request or specific ;legal advice, and should not be closed on that basis.